# How do I capture the input value on passing another value to another form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have  input fields which gets its value from a form in a modal,

using jQuery this is an example:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Search').click(function () {
            $("#txt1").val($("#seach1").val());
            $("#txt2").val($("#search2").val());
            $("#txt3").val($("#search3").val());
        });
    });
```

The form on the page has the following ids `#txt1,txt2,txt3`

its input field looks as follows

```
<input onkeydown="updateDetails(this.id);" onfocus="updateDetails(this.id);" onblur="clearDetails(this.id);" onkeyup="updateDetails(this.id);"  maxLength="254" id="txt1" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="value: dataSource.view()[0].Database.txt1" />
```

Form in modal sends its value correctly to the page form but when I save the form, the form is saved with blank value.

-- should i create an onkeydown Event?

thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#Search').click(function () {
    $("#txt1").val($("#seach1").val()).trigger("change");
    $("#txt2").val($("#search2").val()).trigger("change");
    $("#txt3").val($("#search3").val()).trigger("change");
});
```

Then add "onchange" event to your input field.

Comment: THANK YOU!   I have added onchange="updateDetails(this.id);" and testing now